# I need to place a column of values into categorical bins

Tags: python, dataframe, binning

I am cleaning up a dataframe about apples. I am supposed to put the values from the "Age" column into categorical bins. However when I get to the part of actually placing the values into bins, labeling them, etc. Either all of my values end up in the first category (code 1), or it seems to drop every value that doesn't fit the first bin (code 2).

Try 1

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Fav': ['Gala', 'Fuji', 'GALA', 'GRANNY SMITH', 'Red Delicious',
                'All of them!', 'Pink lady', 'IDK', 'granny smith', 'Honey Crisp',
                'Fuji', 'Golden delish', 'McIntosh', 'Empire', 'Gala'  ],
        'Age': [10,'Old enough', '30+', 'No', 21, 19, 43,37,29,7,28,70,60,52,49]}
apples = pd.DataFrame(data)

# create True/False index
B = apples['AGE'].str.isnumeric()

# for the index, fill missing values with False
B = B.fillna(False)

# select Age column for only those False values from index and code as missing
apples.loc[~B 'AGE'] = np.nan

#change strings to floats (when I test calue counts up to this point everything is there and correct)
apples.loc[~B,'AGE'] = apples.loc[~B,'Q3: AGE'].str.replace('\%', '', regex=True).astype(float)

#binning (at this point it puts ALL values in the "unknown" bin.)
bins = [0,1, 18, 26, 36, 46, 56]
labels = ['17 and under', '18-25', '26-35', '36-45', '46-55', '56+']
apples['AGE'] = pd.cut(B, bins, labels)

#check my result 
apples['AGE'].value_counts()
```

Try 2

```
# create True/False index
B = apples['AGE'].str.isnumeric()

# for the index, fill missing values with False
B = B.fillna(False)

# select Age column for only those False values from index and code as missing
apples.loc[~B 'AGE'] = np.nan

#change strings to floats (when I test value counts up to this point everything is there and correct)
apples.loc[~B,'AGE'] = apples.loc[~B,'Q3: AGE'].str.replace('\%', '', regex=True).astype(float)

#binning (at this point I lose all values except the 'unknown" bin.)
apples['AGE']= pd.cut(~B, bins=[0,1,18, 26, 36, 46, 56, 100] ,
                         labels=['unknown','17 and under', '18-25', '26-35', '36-45', '46-55', '56+'])
#check my result 
apples['AGE'].value_counts()
```

Any other way that I attempt to format this code gives me the type error "'<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'"

Comment: Can you pls share some sample data for apples['Age']? Do include all types - number/string/incorrect entries that might be present. You are  trying to replace the data in Age with one of the `labels` text right?

Comment: Do you just want invalid ages to be nan?

Comment: I wanted the invalid ages to be nan and then group in the "unknown" and the other ages grouped in their bins

Answer (score 0):

Although not explicitly listed in the "categories", `Nan` values do have their own category in a categorical, as seen by their distinct code `-1`:

```py
apples.Age = pd.to_numeric(apples.Age, errors='coerce')
bins = [1, 18, 26, 36, 46, 56, 100]
labels = ['17 and under', '18-25', '26-35', '36-45', '46-55', '56+']
apples.Age = pd.cut(apples.Age, bins=bins, labels=labels)
print(apples)
print(apples.Age.cat.codes)

# Output:
              Fav           Age
0            Gala  17 and under
1            Fuji           NaN
2            GALA           NaN
3    GRANNY SMITH           NaN
4   Red Delicious         18-25
5    All of them!         18-25
6       Pink lady         36-45
7             IDK         36-45
8    granny smith         26-35
9     Honey Crisp  17 and under
10           Fuji         26-35
11  Golden delish           56+
12       McIntosh           56+
13         Empire         46-55
14           Gala         46-55

0     0
1    -1
2    -1
3    -1
4     1
5     1
6     3
7     3
8     2
9     0
10    2
11    5
12    5
13    4
14    4
dtype: int8
```