# Put these values into the following categorical bins (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

The task is to put these values into the following categorical bins: `unknown`, `17 and under`, `18-25`, `26-35`, `36-45`, `46-55`, and `56+`.
​

- The category labels should exactly match the above.
- Missing values should be replaced with the `unknown` category
- To make things easier and avoid ambiguity, let's say that any value with text, even if we could determine the age, will be binned with the `unknown` category. For example: `sixty-nine` should be coded as `unknown`, `45-55` should be coded as `unknown`, `59 on the day after Halloween` should be coded as `unknown`, etc.
- Ensure that the category labels are unordered but reorder the categories so that 'unknown' is listed in the first position. This is not really needed but will help us grade your assignment. The categories should be listed as follows: `Index(['unknown', '17 and under', '18-25', '26-35', '36-45', '46-55', '56+'], dtype='object')`

The error I keep getting is: ***Bin labels must be one fewer than the number of bin edges***

*This Code is Already Provided*

```
# create True/False index
    age_index = candy['Q3: AGE'].str.isnumeric()

# for the index, fill missing values with False
    age_index = age_index.fillna(False)

# select Age column for only those False values from index and code as missing
    candy.loc[~age_index, 'Q3: AGE'] = np.nan
```

**This is my code**

```
bins = [-float('inf'), 17, 25, 35, 45, 55, float('inf')]
labels = ['unknown', '17 and under', '18-25', '26-35', '36-45', '46-55', '56+']

candy['age_cat'] = pd.cut(pd.to_numeric(candy['Q3: AGE'], errors='coerce'), bins=bins, labels=labels, include_lowest=True)

candy['age_cat'].fillna('unknown', inplace=True)

candy['age_cat'] = pd.Categorical(candy['age_cat'], categories=['unknown', '17 and under', '18-25', '26-35', '36-45', '46-55', '56+'], ordered=False)

print(candy['age_cat'])
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73255956/2173773

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the input data `candy` ? See [mcve] for more information

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

plz provide minimal and reproducible input to solve your problem

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['45-55', '20', '56', '35'], columns=['age'])
```

df

```
    age
0   45-55
1   20
2   56
3   35
```

**Code**

Add -1 as a boundary to bins. and use `to_numeric` & `cut`

```
bins = [-float('inf'), -1, 17, 25, 35, 45, 55, float('inf')]
labels = ['unknown', '17 and under', '18-25', '26-35', '36-45', '46-55', '56+']
df['age_cat'] = pd.cut(pd.to_numeric(df['age'], errors='coerce'), 
                       bins=bins, labels=labels)\
                  .fillna('unknown')
```

df

```
    age     age_cat
0   45-55   unknown
1   20      18-25
2   56      56+
3   35      26-35
```

order of age_cat column

```
Categories (7, object): ['unknown' < '17 and under' < '18-25' < '26-35' < '36-45' < '46-55' < '56+']
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
bins = [-float('inf'), 17, 25, 35, 45, 55, float('inf')]
labels = ['unknown', '17 and under', '18-25', '26-35', '36-45', '46-55', '56+']
candy['age_cat'] = pd.cut(pd.to_numeric(candy['Q3: AGE'], errors='coerce'), bins=bins, labels=labels, include_lowest=True)
candy['age_cat'].fillna('unknown', inplace=True)
candy['age_cat'] = pd.Categorical(candy['age_cat'], categories=['unknown', '17 and under', '18-25', '26-35', '36-45', '46-55', '56+'], ordered=False)
print(candy['age_cat'])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).